# Formula for inserting value from Sheet 1 if word matches in Sheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets in excel.

Sheet1 has 4 columns with following pattern.

```
ID      Name 1          Name 2       Name 3   
AAA1    Ant            P.Ant         Ant IgE   
AAA2    Peanut         Peanut.IgE    Peanut.IgE Serum   
AAA3    Tomato       
AAA4    Apple          Apple.IgE
```

Sheet 2 has following two columns:

```
Name        ID
Ant         AAA1  
Grass       #NA#  
Apple.IgE   AAA4  
Tomato      AA3   
Mango       #NA#
```

I would like to check whether whole text in column A (sheet 2) exist in any of columns between B to D in sheet 1.

If yes, display ID mentioned in column A (from sheet 1) against particular row in Sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

A bit long-winded (and doesn't tally with your result for 'Tomato') but please try in Sheet2 B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!B:B,0)),INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!C:C,0))),INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!D:D,0)))
```